# Rename a single column while using select * in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am selecting all column of my table (eg 40 columns) and i want to rename only one column (e.g col20 ). how can i rename this column in my select query while selecting all column using select *. I don't want to write the name of all column. one more thing i also don't want to change the order of column in my table

Answer (score 6):

Short answer is, you can't.

Either you have to select all the columns individually, using

```
select col1, col2, col3, ..., col20 as NewCol, ...., col40 from table
```

or use

```
select * from table
```

You can't have both.

Another option is there which you can use like below, but this will add an extra column in the output.

```
select t.*, t.col20 as NewCol from table t
```